# Lifecycle hooks in angular

Tags: html, css, node.js, angular, typescript

In this app there are three components- employee, customer and view. When a user fill either employee or customer form, his data should be shown in view. And if another user enter some data in either of these forms, the previous view should dissappear showing the new data. But here the previous data is not dissappearing after entering the new data in a different form. I mean If we first enter the Employee data, then data should be shown below the form and after that if we fill the customer form, the Employee data should dissappear and new customer data should be shown below customer from. Here I have used ngOnchanges to detect the change in input data to View. Here is my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfbevl

Answer (score 4):

Remove `<app-view>` from customer and employee component and add it it app.component.

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fdcots?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

**app.component.html**

```
<app-employee (dataChange)="data = $event"></app-employee>
<app-customer (dataChange)="data = $event"></app-customer>


<app-view [getData]="data"></app-view>
```

**employee.component.ts and customer.component**

```
@Output() dataChange = new EventEmitter();

 onSubmit(){
   this.submitted=true;
   this.data = this.diagonastics;
   this.dataChange.emit(this.data)
   this.employeeForm.reset();
 }
```